# Facebook app running on iPad 1 with iOS 5.1.1 crashes at launch

Tags: ipad, facebook, ios

The Facebook app (version 5.3 from Dec 13, 2012) running on iPad 1 with iOS 5.1.1 crashes at launch.

It always used to work then I restored to factory settings whilst upgrading to iOS 5.1.1 now it crashes on launch and returns user to home screen. I have deleted the app and all it's data, restarted the iPad and re-installed the app. Other apps from the store and that account run fine, but I'm at a loss what to do next?

Comment: same here. I removed the app and installed it again. turned the ipad off, then on, but still it crashes everytime. I'm beginning to think this has some connection to the updated iOS. I have iPad 1 - iOS 5.1.1. And I just checked, facebook updated the app that fits with the iPad that runs an iOS 6. I dunno. Maybe.

Comment: Same with my iPhone 4s. I'm jailbroken and I dont want to upgrade because I will loose the jailbreak. But, i hope there is another solution